# Snakemake: Pipeline to Process Samples with Multiple Input Files

Tags: snakemake

I'm new to Snakemake and I'm trying to put together my own pipeline after completing the tutorial and I'm running into some issues when trying to create a pipeline to handle samples with multiple input files. I'm trying to create a pipeline that does the following steps:

1. Read all the input files present in a sample directory (ex. data/experiment/sample/)and run a python script on each of them producing an output file into a results directory (ex. results/experiment/sample/)
2. Combine all the results files present in the results directory into a single file (ex. results/experiment/sample/merged.txt)

An example directory structure I am working with is as follows (the total number of files per sample may different depending on the sample):

```
data
    experiment
        Sample_1
            Sample_1_0.txt
            Sample_1_1.txt
            Sample_1_2.txt
```

My config file as it stands now is as follows (trying to run the pipeline for a single sample):

```
exp_dir: experiment
sample: Sample_1
distance: 450
max_wavelength: 710
min_wavelength: 575
```

My pipeline that I've tried to put together is as follows in my Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

EXP_DIR=config["exp_dir"]
SAMPLE=config["sample"]
FINAL_FILE=f"results/{EXP_DIR}/{SAMPLE}/{SAMPLE}_complete.txt"

wcs = glob_wildcards("data" + "/"  + EXP_DIR + "/" + SAMPLE + "/" + SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt")

rule all:
    input:
        FINAL_FILE

rule detect_peaks:
    input:
        "data" + "/"  + EXP_DIR + "/" + SAMPLE + "/" + SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt"
    output:
        "results/" + EXP_DIR + "/" + SAMPLE + "/" + SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt"
    params:
        distance=config["distance"],
        max_wavelength=config["max_wavelength"],
        min_wavelength=config["min_wavelength"]
    shell:
        "python scripts/peak_detection.py -i {input} -o {output} -d {params.distance} "
        "-m {params.min_wavelength} -x {params.max_wavelength}"


rule agg_files:
    input:
        expand("data/results" + "/"  + EXP_DIR + "/" + SAMPLE + "/" + SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt", ts=wcs["rep"])
    output:
        FINAL_FILE
    output:
        "python scripts/combine_peaks.py -i {input} -o {output}"
```

When I try to build the DAG before running the pipeline I get the following error:
TypeError in file XXXX, line 29:
tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Any help/suggestions as to how I can fix this issue or improve my pipeline would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error is due to how you access the contents of `wcs`.  It should be `wcs.rep` instead of `wcs["rep"]`, the underlying structure is a tuple, not a dict.

The rest of your snakefile will work but here are a few style tips:

- Replace your exp_dir sample setup with just a path to the experiments.  I like to keep these in the config under a `paths` key.  So your config would be:

```
paths:
  raw_data: "data/experiment/Sample_1/Sample_1_{rep}.txt"
  output: "results/experiment/Sample_1/Sample_1_complete.txt"
```

It's more flexible in that a user can decide later they want to change the file tree and it will still work.  You can also add wildcards a bit easier, say you had multiple experiments and samples.  You can glob_wildcards all of those and expand (with a zip!) and everything will work basically the same.

- Ignoring that, consider using f-strings or `os.path.join` to make your filenames.

```
 "data" + "/"  + EXP_DIR + "/" + SAMPLE + "/" + SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt"
 # vs
 f"data/{EXP_DIR}/{SAMPLE}/{SAMPLE}_{{rep}}.txt"
 # or
 os.path.join("data", EXP_DIR, SAMPLE, SAMPLE + "_{rep}.txt")
```

- You don't need to use params to pass in a config value, you can just use it directly:

```
-x {params.max_wavelength}
# vs
-x {config[max_wavelength]}
```

- Instead of using the shell directive, consider using the [`script`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#external-scripts) directive to simplify passing in snakemake variables.  If you do this, disregard my previous suggestion.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you for your comment and extra tips!